# Installing Jenkins onminikube shows Failed to pull image "jenkins/jenkins:2.303.3-jdk11"

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

```
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  51s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned jenkins/jenkins-0 to minikube
  Normal   BackOff    31s                kubelet, minikube  Back-off pulling image "jenkins/jenkins:2.303.3-jdk11"
  Warning  Failed     31s                kubelet, minikube  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    17s (x2 over 47s)  kubelet, minikube  Pulling image "jenkins/jenkins:2.303.3-jdk11"
  Warning  Failed     1s (x2 over 32s)   kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull image "jenkins/jenkins:2.303.3-jdk11": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Warning  Failed     1s (x2 over 32s)   kubelet, minikube  Error: ErrImagePull
```

The above error is what I am seeing, when trying to install Jenkins on a minikube cluster. I am using this link and following along: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/kubernetes/

appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Since it times out trying to pull the images, check if the Internet access is there, specifically if you can access docker.io, try running something like `curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/` or `nc -zv registry-1.docker.io 443`.

Comment: Which way are you installing jenkins? helm/yaml/operator?

Comment: I am using helm to install. I am trying to install simple minikube dashboard (forget jenkins for the moment) and its also failing to pull images. I see curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}
I am using a ubuntu laptop(20.04) infact a dell machine scratched to linux. i started minikube using minikube start --driver=docker. do i need to do some proxy setup? i am not behind any proxy

Comment: You don't need to be behind proxy. Just out of curiosity, are you logged in (as in docker login), if you are, could you log out and try again?

Comment: yes, i tried logout and login again. same issue. one question, do i need to use virtualbox for minikube or docker also works

Comment: Docker should be fine, but it is up to you which driver to use. virtualbox will operate with VMs (startup time wont be as fast and resource utilization will be higher), docker will do containers instead of VMs. I only ever used docker, never had problems so far.

Comment: @sbolla Have you managed to move it forward? You can also try to `docker pull $image` manually without kubernetes part to see what happens. So far this is either network related or incorrect image.

Comment: yes, i managed. i tried with minikube with virtualbox and that worked. but, wanted to get docker working. finally, i deleted everything (even reinstalled ubuntu) and re-setup k8s cluster with lastest k8s version (before i tried with --version=1.190.0) used: minikube start --driver=docker. and then followed the official jenkins install with helm3, that too latest, lts

Comment: Great, you can [answer your own question and then accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). It may be useful for other community members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with minikube with virtualbox and that worked out of the box.
But, wanted to get docker working, which I wasn't able to.

Finally, I deleted everything (even reinstalled ubuntu) and re-setup k8s cluster with latest k8s version (before i tried with --version=1.19.0 of k8s)

I used: minikube start --driver=docker. and then followed the official jenkins install with helm3, that too latest, lts –